# On linux kernel can atomic operations for eg atomic_inc, atomic_dec etc protect a variable under multi core environment?

Tags: linux-kernel

Atomic operations protect a variable in a multi threading environment, but is it suitable for mutlicore environment?

Comment: Different threads may run on different cores. So knowing that atomic operations are safe for multi-threading processes indicates that atomic operations are safe for multi-core processes. (on specific architectures).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. They are typically implemented via atomic memory bus operations and so will work just the same for a multi-core scenario.

In fact, if you know the data you are protecting is only accessed by different threads (tasks) on the same core, it is probably cheaper to implement the protection via other means, such as disable preemption and/or interrupts. Atomic operation are specifically meant for situation where that is not enough. such as multi-core systems.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-threaded essentially means that there are multiple tasks running (processes). According to Wikipedia:

> Atomicity is a guarantee of isolation from interrupts, signals, concurrent processes and threads.

This is because these operations are treated as if they are one since it is not being interrupted by anything. Therefore, multiple threads can perform these operations of course, but only one at a time because a processor can only perform one operation, or atomic operation at a time.
The same logic goes for multi-core processes where there are multiple processors trying to access the same data. This is done through mutual exclusion which ensures that a critical code block never gets accessed more than once at the same time. In software terms, this means that it uses locks to ensure that the multiple processors cannot access it while in use.